# How to Dynamically Import SCSS Stylesheets in Nuxt using an Environment Variable

Tags: javascript, performance, vue.js, sass, nuxt.js

We are running Nuxt in a monorepo and things are working well. We are utilizing a /base directory containing our reusable components and stylesheets, and each project has its own subdirectory within a /projects directory.

Our global variables/mixins are being added to the base nuxt.config.js via the @nuxtjs/style-resources module which we then extend and import into the project's own nuxt.config.js.

In our components, we are hoping to dynamically import a project-specific stylesheet using an environment variable. We currently have something like:

```
//component-name.vue

<template>
  //Template things
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    data() {
      return {
        projectPrefix: process.env.PROJECT_PREFIX
      }
    }
  }
}
</script>

<style lang="scss">
  @import 'base/assets/styles/scss/_component-name.scss';

  //We would like to import the JUST ONE of the following stylesheets based on projectPrefix
  @import './projects/project-foo/assets/styles/scss/_component-name.scss';
  @import './projects/project-bar/assets/styles/scss/_component-name.scss';
  @import './projects/project-baz/assets/styles/scss/_component-name.scss';
  ...
</style>
```

At the moment, everything works fine in terms of the styles being displayed correctly per project. The problem is that we also include a bunch of unused styles in this way.

Does anyone know of a good solution for how we might be able to dynamically import a stylesheet based on an environment variable?

Answer (score 1):

You could create a component for env variable. Something like:

```js
<template>
  <component-with-style-a v-if="projectPrefix === 'A'" />
  <component-with-style-b v-else />
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    data() {
      return {
        projectPrefix: process.env.PROJECT_PREFIX
      }
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: This is an interesting approach as it would allow us to have specific styles on each sub-component. I assume you are suggesting an "empty" component that only has a style associated with it, and the HTML that gets rendered is still only at the initial component level, right? I feel like this would be a bit of a hack, and may add a bit too much to the workflow of registering and maintaining each of these components, but it seems like it could work if there aren't better solutions. Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: yes, that's indeed the downside. Ideally you would avoid markup without any semantic meaning. If you find a better solution, let me know ;)